# R: remove characters before a specific string

Tags: r, text-mining, gsub, string-substitution

I am trying to remove characters from specific words from twitter text mining, lamentably my text has wrong word and ending because of accent:

my result: `â€œuna  muriÃ`

result expected: `una murio`

I am using gsub :

```
mach_text = gsub("una$,"", ignore.case=T, mach_text)
```

Pd: I am working with Spanish text and lamentably my text have  word ending because accent, I did try with:

```
mach_text = iconv(mach_text, "latin1")
```

But doesn´t work.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want `una muri`??

Comment: I don't code in R but it looks like you have some typos.

Comment: @Onyambu  I want: "una" and "murio"

Comment: In your code I mean.

Comment: what is the `Encoding(mach_text)`?

Comment: How will it change the last character in `muriA` to `O`? Which encoding?

Comment: @Onyambu I  did try using 
mach_text = gsub("muri", "murio", ignore.case=T, mach_text )
Works fine but not for "una".

Comment: @Onyambu I did try encoding("utf-8") but dont work

Comment: You  did not answer what do you get when you do `Encoding(mach_text)`?

Comment: @Onyambu  "unknown" and "UTF-8"

Comment: `iconv(x,"utf-8","latin1","")`?

Comment: @Onyambu I did run iconv(x,"utf-8","latin1","") 
and :
"unknown" and "UTF-8"  again.

Comment: No this cannot give you what you just said. Try it again. You ran the wrong line. `icov` will never return an encoding

Comment: @Onyambu, Sorry,  I did run again and give me (extract):
                                                                            
 [9999] "RT deadmantetris: Una mujer fantastica"                                                                                                            
[10000] "RT biobio: Estreno en TV de \"Una Mujer fantastica"

Comment: if i run encoding(mach_text),
"unknown" and "latin1"

Comment: Is that what you needed?

Comment: @Onyambu Yes!! great! Thanks for your time and patient!